# hide label of x-axis using css in morris js

Tags: javascript, css

as you can see here http://jsbin.com/acOmiQU/1/edit the label is too long to be displayed on x, but the tag has no class, how can I hide it?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the years 2006 - 2012, it displays fine for me on latest chrome (31).

Comment: @JustinWood link updated lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try targeting:

```
text[text-anchor="middle"]{
  display:none
}
```

Apparently it's unique for X-axis labels.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/AKIJUteW/1/edit

Comment: thanks so much! it worked! btw where to u find it? I thought the y and x text are together?

Comment: I simple opened Chrome Dev tools and inspected label elements for X and Y. For Y it was `<text text-anchor="end">` and for X it was `<text text-anchor="middle">`

Comment: Too bad this hack affects Donut charts labels too, since they share the same text-anchor id :(

Answer (score 2):

Include this in the configuration options to hide X axis:

axes:"y"

Include this in the configuration options to hide Y axis:

axes:"x"

Answer (score 1):

```
Morris.Bar({
// ...
xLabelAngle: 1,
});
```

Try changing the xLabelAngle option to 1 degree value - it generates labels on the `x-axis` with a attribute of `y="313.542402245"` to all `x axis` labels.

Now, simply target all the x axis labels through CSS like this...

```
text[y="313.542402245"] {
display: none;
}
```

**EDITED**

Another solution is to hide x-axis label by editing morris js file ---

Find this code into morris js

```
Bar.prototype.drawXAxisLabel = function(xPos, yPos, text) {
var label;
return label = this.raphael.text(xPos, yPos, text).attr('font-size', this.options.gridTextSize).attr('font-family', this.options.gridTextFamily).attr('font-weight', this.options.gridTextWeight).attr('fill', this.options.gridTextColor);
};
```

and replace it with the below one.

```
Bar.prototype.drawXAxisLabel = function (xPos, yPos, text) {
var label;
return label = this.raphael.text(xPos, yPos, '').attr('font-size', this.options.gridTextSize).attr('font-family', this.options.gridTextFamily).attr('font-weight', this.options.gridTextWeight).attr('fill', this.options.gridTextColor);
};
```

Comment: I was searching for how to set the alignment of x-axis label vertical and thinking to somehow apply CSS in xLabelFormat but this was super easy, quick and acurate. Your answer helped . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to have an update on this one. I had a problem when I use "display: none;" on the text of x-axis. The overall size of the svg got affected specially the y-axis label where it will only show 2 characters/digits at most because the other characters/digits got overflowed.

So what I used is:

```
text[text-anchor="middle"]{
    opacity: 0;
}
```